# Can I display UTC offset rather than local offset in the desktop calendar applet?

Tags: time, calendar, timezone, gnome-clocks

I have configured some world clocks in the Gnome Clocks application, and they appear on the Ubuntu desktop calendar as expected, see below. (I don't know the correct name for the "desktop calendar" applet.)

However, the timezone offsets are relative to local time, so right now it displays:

```
New York -5
UTC -1
London 0
```

instead of:

```
New York -6
UTC 0
London +1
```

I habitually read offsets as UTC offsets, so this creates confusion for me, and more importantly my colleagues when I discuss meeting times!

Is there an option to change the offset reference? (It's hard to find the setting since I don't know the name of the applet.)

[image: Desktop calendar showing the current time in London and New York]